# Как сделать ,чтоб иконки были на одном уровне

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтоб эти иконки встали на один уровень снизу,а не так чтобы одно выше,другое ниже
(Эти иконки находятся в div class="cicons"
Помогите,пожалуйста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SanFrancisco';
    font-display: swap;
    src: url("../fonts/SFProText-Light.eot");
    src: local("O"), url("../fonts/SFProText-Light.woff") format("woff"), 
            url("../fonts/SFProText-Light.ttf") format("truetype"), 
            url("../fonts/SFProText-Light.svg") format("svg");
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family:'SanFrancisco';
}

.navbar {
  height: 2.7em;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(70, 67, 68);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-list a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'SanFrancisco';
}

.navbar img {
  min-width: 15px;
  height: auto;
  width: 15px;
  height: auto;
}

.srv {
  width: 50px;
}

.cicons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
  column-gap: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.cover {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'SanFrancisco';
}

.cover>h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.iphone>img {
  width: 1150px;
  height: auto;
}

.cover a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'sanFrancisco';
  color: rgb(0, 102, 204);
  line-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Iphone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/style.css">

</head>

<body>
   <div class="navbar">
    <img src="static/images/apple.png" alt="">
    <ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a href="#">Магазин</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">IPad</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">IPhone</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AirPods</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TV и Дом</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Только в Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Аксессуары</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Поддержка</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="icons">
        <i class='fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass' style='color:#ffffff'></i>
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bag" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
         <path d="M8 1a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.5 2.5V4h-5v-.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 8 1zm3.5 3v-.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0-7 0V4H1v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h-3.5zM2 5h12v9a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V5z"/ style='color:#ffffff'>
</svg>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cicons">
    <img src="static/images/iphonexsbu_dark_large (1).svg">
    <img src="static/images/iphonexsbu_dark_large (1).svg">
    <img src="static/images/iphonexsbu_dark_large (1).svg">
    <img class="srv" src="static/images/Background.png">
   </div>

   <div class="cover">
    <h3>IPhone13Pro</h3>
    <H1>Просто.Нереально.</H1>
    <p><a href="#">Подробнее ></a></p>
    <div class="iphone">
        <img src="static/images/2os8un3e1mq847l41ih3zhujtzv4z0pe.png">
        
    </div>
   </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать через grid

50px - это width иконок
10px - это расстояние между твоими иконками

```css
.your-steps {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 50px);
    column-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="your-steps">
    <div class="step">
        <div class="cicons">
            <img src="static/images/iphonexsbu_dark_large (1).svg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
        <div class="cicons">
             <img src="static/images/iphonexsbu_dark_large (1).svg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
        <div class="cicons">
             <img src="static/images/iphonexsbu_dark_large (1).svg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
        <div class="cicons">
            <img class="srv" src="static/images/Background.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как сделать между иконками расстояние,пробел?

Comment: Ты можешь регулировать column-gap по пикселям, от него зависит расстояние между иконками

Answer (score 0):

.cicons {align-items: flex-end;} и все картинки встанут по нижнему уровню.
У вас стоит center - поэтому они центрированы

Comment: А как сделать между иконками расстояние,пробел?

Comment: @Bebrik Очень просто - .cicons {column-gap: 15px;} - вместо 15 можно любое другое число

Comment: Пожалуйста, оборачивайте код в апострофы.

Comment: спасибо большое )